# Can I create a function at runtime by evaluating a string?

Tags: haskell, eval

In my program for solving discrete maths, I want to let the user input a string of logic operations; *e.g.,* if the user inputs `let f (x:y:_) = x && y`, then I would get a function `f` for use in the rest of the program.  In GHCi, I can easily test my program by inputting `let f (x:y:_) = x && y`.

I have no idea how to achieve this task.  I have taken a look into the [`eval`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/plugins/1.5.1.3/doc/html/System-Eval-Haskell.html) function from the `plugins` package, but it seems not to be the right function.  Can I do this in Haskell?

The code I'm planning to use this with is:

```
type TruthTable = [[Bool]]
type TruthTableResult = [([Bool], Bool)]

solveTable :: ([Bool] -> Bool) -> Integer -> (TruthTableResult)
solveTable f n = let table = truthTable n
                     result = map f table
                 in  zipWith (\v r -> (v, r)) table result
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no standard Haskell function, because Haskell is complied, not interpreted. However, there are libraries that allow you to read and compile Haskell code at run time. One of them is [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint). Example for your case:

```
import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter

main = do
    -- fExpr is a Haskell code supplied by your user as a String
    let fExpr = "let f (x:y:_) = x && y in f"
    -- Create an interpreter that runs fExpr
    r <- runInterpreter $ do
            setImports ["Prelude"]
            interpret fExpr (const True :: [Bool] -> Bool)
    -- run it and get an interface to the function
    case r of
        Left err -> putStrLn $ "Ups... " ++ (show err)
        Right f  -> do
            print $ f [True, False]
            print $ f [True, True]
```

More examples available [here](http://projects.haskell.org/hint/).

Comment: Common Lisp is often compiled and has an `eval` function so that's not really an argument. ;)

Comment: @kqr: more generally, there is no such connection at all. Both Python and Java produce bytecode for a VM, but Python has ``eval``, while Java doesn't (and Clojure, which produces JVM bytecode too, does). OpenCL is C99, so it's compiled, right? But I can construct and run an OpenCL kernel in runtime, which is essentially ``eval``. And so on.

Comment: @kqr That's true. What I meant that interpreted languages usually get an `eval` implementation for free. Compiled ones must somehow include an interpreter or compiler. And this is what _hint_ is - a wrapper around the GHC API.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly for my program. I can now let the user input the formula, and get the truth table. However, I find that the executable program is not a self-contained executable, it requires ghc and hint for execution...

Comment: @code4j I'm afraid that's the price for being able to run an arbitrary Haskell expression. You could try [plugins](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins), but it seems that there is some problem with recent versions of GHC. Another option would be to write your own language for entering boolean formulas. A simple language consisting of just variables, boolean operators and parentheses would be quite simple to define and parse using something like Parsec.

Comment: @code4j: think about it.  How is a haskell program going to know how to run any arbitrary string without something equivalent to a full version of GHC?

Answer (score 10):

You are writing an `eval` function - a form of runtime metaprogramming.

```
eval :: String -> a
```

If the string represents a Haskell program, then you must parse the string, type check it, and then compile it to a target interpreter or runtime. This requires access to the compiler as a library, either exported as a runtime service (in an interpreter) or as a separate package (as for a compiler).

The GHC implementation of Haskell has several libraries for doing runtime evaluation of Haskell code:

- via the GHCi interpreter-  [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint)
- via the compiler - [plugins](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/plugins/1.5.3.0/doc/html/System-Eval-Haskell.html)

These apply only if your input language is Haskell.

If instead your input string represents a program in some other language, then you are looking for a DSL interpreter. This can be done by writing your own interpreter for the input language (or reusing a library if it is a common language).

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that Haskell has no "eval" function, unlike interpreted languages which can do this quite easily (after all, they have the interpreter handy and already running).

You can include the Haskell compiler as a library: see http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/As_a_library. This is the nearest thing to what you ask for.

However it sounds like you don't want the whole of Haskell here; what you are really want is a different language which may have Haskell-like syntax but is not the whole of Haskell. If so then the real solution is to define that language and write a parser for it. The [Parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec) library is the place to start for that.

Comment: Another alternative is for OP to write their program as a library and let the users input their functions by writing a program in Haskell using OPs library.